# Can I remove the power wires of USB 3.0 and still use data wires?

Tags: usb, usb-device

So I have this SATA to USB converter for 2.5 inch HDD [image]
I want to cut away the power port (5v) and use the remaining data port with an separately powered (12v) 3.5 inch HDD. I was wondering if this will work or not (and possible risks for the HDD).

Comment: You cannot use the data without ground. 100% for sure.

Comment: Does that connector generate the 12v rail internally or just not provide 12v and hope the device is ok with it?  Probably the easiest solution would be to connect your external supply to the 12v pin on that connector.  That way you could leave the USB 5V connected.

Comment: @mkeith for this reason the SATA data connector includes three ground pins, the power connector is not required for signal ground

Comment: @Jasen the USB data pins cannot function if the USB device does not share ground with the USB host. They are not true differential pins. The GND is required. THAT was my point. Since I was not totally clear on what the OP intended, I wanted to caution about that.

Comment: Just use a sata extension cable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to communicate with the other device, you need 3 things:

1. Data lines are connected.
2. Grounds are connected together so that all voltages are referenced to the same ground level (you don't want things to float relatively to one another)
3. Both devices need to be powered.

There is no need for the device to be specifically powered by your USB's power line. The slave device has no idea what's powering it. It's receiving its 5V or 12V or whatever it needs, and it has no way to tell what's supplying it. If it's powered, it can talk. All you need to do is to supply the 12V to the device's supply pins (and connect grounds, of course). These SATA to USB usually have these 12V pins simply unconnected as they're intended for 2.5" drives.

Similarly, USB host doesn't really care what happens to its power line - as long as it's not shorted/pulling too much current. At least, it has nothing to do with the data. You may have seen some external USB-powered CD/DVD drives, that have 2 USB-A connectors - cable splits in two - one USB-A is for power/data, another just for power, and it takes 2 USB ports on your computer to be able to pull enough power. Whatever gives the necessary amps.

Your main issue could be the quality of the supply, you need to make sure grounds are well connected and that you don't introduce too much noise into the system. All in all, it should work. Your biggest problem is actually to find a way to connect your external supply to 12V pins.

Addendum: there are USB to SATA converters, that look exactly like yours, but also have a barrel jack for 12V external supply specifically for this situation:

If you need 12V, you connect it, if you work with 2.5" drive, you simply don't connect it and it draws 5V power from the USB.

Comment: This answer has some problems. An USB device must receive power from USB before it is allowed to start negotiating USB link. So even if it gets power from somewhere else, it is not allowed to try communicating with the host, if host happens to be turned off for example. A device not adhering to these rules is in violation of USB specs and it would not pass USB testing and could not be sold or marketed as an USB device.

Comment: @Justme host turned off? How can that happen? I think it's a pretty obvious assumption that I can't use USB stick with turned off computer? Also, I used USB 2.0 with entirely external power, not from the host. Soldered some stuff.

Comment: I understand you can violate USB specs and make incompliant devices by just soldering some stuff up. It does not mean it is advisable to do so, with the added risk of damage to motherboard or the device. The externally powered device is not allowed to try signaling the host to start enumeration, unless the host gives the device 5V as a sign that it's powered on and ready to detect devices. If you force it, the device will be pushing current over data wire to an unpowered PC. A standard externally powered device will not communicate unless it sees 5V from PC.

Comment: I understand the violation of specs part, and agree that it's not recommended, but I still don't understand why the PC would be unpowered. As an advanced PC user, I never use USB devices with my PC turned off.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it cleared many things. So there's this old IDE to usb converter https://brandedhouse.com.pk/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/SATA-to-IDE.jpg , as you can see it has separate connections for power and data. I'm trying to do the same thing but with usb 3.0. (I know about the proper converter but I couldn't wait for 1-2 days required for shipping)

Comment: @Dexter the bottom line is, you can do it the way you want, as long as you understand the risks and where the problems can come from.

Comment: @justme, yes that's a requirement for USB and is satisifed by the circuit inside the USB-SATA bridge it's not needed for SATA

Answer (score 0):

yes you can

But there's another option, that is to add a extension cable to the usb SATA interface,  you can do this by cutting the shroud off the SATA plug on one end of a SATA-SATA data cable until it fits into the SATA plug on the usb adaptor. (so you have springy contacts touching springy contacts)

the 180 degree end rotation cancels the 180 degree cable rotation so all the signals come out in the right place.